# Mapping and Replacing an Element of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

In my code, I have an array of elements. One of those elements is not a string (`<a/>` element). I want to map through that array and find the element and, replace that element with the string 'error'. Here is the array.  How can I achieve what I want?

```
const arr = ['my', 'array', '<a/>', 'is'];
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what is a `string` element?

Comment: I was just trying to say an element that does not contain the </> characters. I didn't explain myself very clearly I think

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkHTML(str) {
  let ele = document.createElement('div');
  ele.innerHTML = str;

  //check if node is of text 
  for ( let child of ele.childNodes){
    if(child.nodeType !=3) return "error"
  }
  
  return str;
}

let arr=["my","<a/>","hi","<div>"]
let mappedArr = arr.map(checkHTML)
console.log(mappedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do it

```js
var arr = ['my', 'array', '<a/>', 'is'];
const regex = /^<\w+\/>$/
arr = arr.map(u => 
   regex.test(u)?'error':u
);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with the help of `RegEx` by using `String.match()` method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = ['my', 'array', '<a/>', 'is'];

arr.forEach((str, index) => {
  if (str.match(/<.*>/g)) {
    arr[index] = 'error';
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```